# Google analytics restrictions for store owners

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, module, magento-1, google-analytics

I'm doing freelancing for a client, he owns a Magento website. He has different stores, each store owned by a different owner. He wants to allow some stores to have access to gooogle analytics for **their own shop only**. And restrict others from using google analytics.

Is that feasible using some existing module? Or should I write a custom module for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's feasible with Magento out of the box.

To do so, you need to:

- go to the backend under **System > Configuration**
- access the **Google API** under the **Sales** tab

Imagine store 1 needs Google Analytics.

In the store view dropdown, select store 1:

[image]

Confirm the popup by clicking OK.

Now that you're on the store 1 view configuration scope:

- click the **Google Analytics** section
- Enable: Yes
- Fill the account number with the account related to store 1
- Save Config

Now, let's say you don't want Google Analytics for store 2.

In the store view dropdown, select store 2:

Now that you're on the store 2 view configuration scope:

- click the **Google Analytics** section
- Enable: No
- Save Config

You can repeat that process for every store you have.

Comment: Wouldn´t it be easier to just do this in GA or is it limited there?

Comment: @Klettseb I assumed that there could be several GA accounts. According to the question, it seems like stores are well defined and separated

Comment: I think thats exactly what im looking for, I upvoted your answer, I will accept it and give you the bounty, in  few days, when I get a chance to try it and confirm that the problem is fixed. Thank you Sir.

Comment: @Lynob no problem I hope it will help you.

Comment: is it available in Magento 1.9x? cause I tagged my question magento 2 by mistake, the client is using magento 1.9

Comment: @Lynob yes it is available for Magento 1.9, the screenshot I posted will of course be different but the process is exactly the same ;)

Comment: @Lynob did you manage to get it working with the solution I provided ?